# Python urllib.urlretrieve Exception Handling

Tags: python

Download the file to half, or because of network problems cause an error or a timeout when downloading this to do with them?

Answer (score 1):

As in [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve)

Changed in version 2.5: urlretrieve() will raise ContentTooShortError when it detects that the amount of data available was less than the expected amount (which is the size reported by a Content-Length header). This can occur, for example, when the download is interrupted.